# How to redirect in url by using .htaccess in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to redirect in url by using htaccess in php?

http://www.example.com/randomstring/2

i would like to go to id page 20 thank

Comment: You can’t use .htaccess in PHP. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mod_rewrite for example in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(randomstring)/([0-9]+)$  /randomstring/$1/ [QSA,R] 
RewriteRule ^(randomstring)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you want to simply redirect from a domain to another just write:

```
RewriteRule ^(randomstring)/([0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2/ [QSA,NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mod_rewrite`, it's a module for apache. You can see the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). `.htaccess` files control the webserver, not php, so you have to look there.

Answer (score 1):

Copy that into your `.htaccess` file in the directory you need it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$2
```

www.domain.tld/asdf/2 --> index.php?id=2
www.domain.tld/asdfa923als/52 --> index.php?id=52

;-)