# using htaccess to modify URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a php project. I want to remove the **".php"** from the URL. Also for -

```
www.mysite.com/gallery.php?gid=2008
```

I want like -

```
www.mysite.com/gallery/2008
```

How can I do this? I want to check it in local wamp server also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `mod_rewrite` in wamp
And add following lines in `.htaccess` of your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?gid=$1 [L]
```

If you want to remove all other PHP but retaining query string, if you have specifc way to handle query string you have write rules accordingly.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/? $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: arent you doing the other way around?

Comment: As I understood question. He want to make /gallery/2008 as external URL.

Comment: RewriteRuel gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?gid=$1 [L] - this is working. but commonly i want to remove .php extention. like reg.php to reg.

Comment: is it generic ? what about the parameters ?

Comment: parameter will be for some pages. that is solved by above. but for parameterless urls like register.php i have used - #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]. but for this, the above is not working(with parameter urls).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this guide.. this should help you get started: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an easy way](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) to allow the URL without .php:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 1):

really multiple question

please search

- [PHP url rewriting using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976809/php-url-rewriting-using-htaccess)
- [How to redirect in url by using .htaccess in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388800/how-to-redirect-in-url-by-using-htaccess-in-php)
- etc

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\?(.*)=(\d+)$ /$1/$2
```